# A block-wise eigenvalue problem

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I recently stumbled across the following eigenvalue problem,
where $\omega$ is the desired eigenvalue, $\Omega$ is a parameter:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
B^* & C
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\vec{u} \\
\vec{v}
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
(\omega - \Omega)^2 & 0 \\
0 & (\omega + \Omega)^2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\vec{u} \\
\vec{v}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

$A, B, C$ are square, non-commuting matrices.
Of course this is a quadratic eigenvalue problem and can be solved
by standard methods.
However, I was wondering if the special structure maybe allowed
further simplifications.

Comment: Is $B^\ast$ the complex conjugate of $B$ or the Hermitian adjoint of $B$?  That is, with $B = [b_{ij}]$, does $B^\ast = [\bar b_{ij}]$ or does $B^\ast = [\bar b_{ji}]$?

Comment: The Hermitian adjoint!